# Placing a tikz under a text

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, compiling, tikz-pic

I drew two tikz pictures and I placed them side by side. The issue I have that that how to make them placed right below the text "The above remarks completes all the steps we need for Green's approch." (please see the commands below). Can you please advise me.

This is my attempt:

```
          \documentclass[10pt]{article}
          \usepackage{pgf,tikz}
          \usepackage{mathrsfs}
          \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
          \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
          \pagestyle{empty}
          \tikzset{
mynode/.style={draw,circle,inner sep=1.9pt,outer sep=1.9pt,fill=white}
}
           \begin{document}
           \definecolor{zzttqq}{rgb}{0.6,0.2,0.}
          The above remarks completes all the steps we need for Green's approch. 
       \begin{figure}
       \centering
       \resizebox{1.2\textwidth}{!}{\scriptsize
       \begin{tikzpicture}

    \node [mynode] (u) at (0,0) {};
    \node [mynode,below left  = of u,label=above:$\scriptsize J_{i}$] (e)  {};
    \node [mynode,below right = of u] (f) {};
    \node [mynode,below right = of e] (d) {};
    \node [mynode,above right = of u] (r) {};
    \node [mynode,above left = of e] (m) {};
    \node [mynode,above right = of m] (s) {};
    \node [mynode,above right = of s] (w) {};
    \node [mynode,above right = of f] (k) {};

    \draw (u) -- (e) 
        (u) -- (f) 
        (e) -- (d) 
        (f) -- (d)
        (r) -- (u)
        (m) -- (e)
        (m) -- (s)
        (w) -- (s)
        (w) -- (r)
        (k) -- (f)
        (r) -- (k)
        (s) -- (u);
    \end{tikzpicture}\hspace{1.2cm}
    \quad 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=.70cm,y=.70cm]
   \fill[line width=0.4pt,color=zzttqq,fill=zzttqq,fill opacity=0.10000000149011612] (4.002,5.) -- (4.,4.) -- (9.,3.986) -- (9.,5.) -- cycle;
   \draw [line width=0.8pt] (2.,6.)-- (6.,6.);
   \draw [line width=0.8pt] (2.,6.)-- (2.,5.);
   \draw [line width=0.8pt] (2.,5.)-- (6.,5.);
   \draw [line width=0.8pt] (6.,5.)-- (6.,6.);
   \draw [line width=0.8pt] (4.,5.)-- (9.,5.);
   \draw [line width=0.8pt] (4.,5.)-- (4.,2.);
   \draw [line width=0.8pt] (4.,2.)-- (9.,2.);
   \draw [line width=0.8pt] (9.,2.)-- (9.,5.);
   \draw [line width=0.8pt] (2.,5.)-- (1.,5.);
   \draw [line width=0.8pt] (1.,5.)-- (1.,3.36);
   \draw [line width=0.8pt] (1.,3.36)-- (4.,3.36);
   \draw [line width=0.8pt] (4.,3.36)-- (4.,1.34);
   \draw [line width=0.8pt] (4.,1.34)-- (2.04,1.34);
   \draw [line width=0.8pt] (2.04,3.36)-- (2.04,1.34);
   \draw [line width=0.8pt] (2.04,3.36)-- (0.,3.37);
   \draw [line width=0.8pt] (0.,3.37)-- (0.,0.422);
   \draw [line width=0.8pt] (0.,0.422)-- (2.396,0.422);
   \draw [line width=0.8pt] (2.396,0.422)-- (2.396,1.34);
   \draw [line width=0.8pt] (2.396,0.422)-- (6.818,0.4);
   \draw [line width=0.8pt] (6.818,0.4)-- (6.818,2.);
   \draw [line width=0.8pt] (9.,2.)-- (8.996,-0.436);
   \draw [line width=0.8pt] (8.996,-0.436)-- (6.818,-0.436);
   \draw [line width=0.8pt] (6.818,-0.436)-- (6.818,0.4);
   \draw [line width=0.8pt] (6.818,-0.436)-- (6.818,-1.228);
   \draw [line width=0.8pt] (6.818,-1.228)-- (1.054,-1.228);
   \draw [line width=0.8pt] (4.794,-1.228)-- (4.816,-2.46);
   \draw [line width=0.8pt] (4.816,-2.46)-- (2.286,-2.46);
   \draw [line width=0.8pt] (2.286,-2.46)-- (2.286,-1.228);
   \draw [line width=0.8pt] (1.054,-1.228)-- (1.054,0.422);
   \draw [line width=0.8pt] (4.,4.)-- (9.,3.986);
   \draw [line width=0.8pt] (5.234,5.)-- (5.234,2.);
   \draw [line width=0.8pt] (6.422,5.)-- (6.444,2.);
   \draw [line width=0.8pt] (7.61,5.)-- (7.61,2.);
   \draw [line width=0.8pt] (4.,3)-- (9.,3);
   \draw (9.0,4.80) node[anchor=north west] {$\tiny R_{e_{i}}$};
   \draw (8.138,4.2) node[anchor=north west] {$\vdots$};
   \draw (6.928,4.2) node[anchor=north west] {$\vdots$};
   \draw (5.762,4.2) node[anchor=north west] {$\vdots$};
   \draw (4.53,4.2) node[anchor=north west] {$\vdots$};
   \end{tikzpicture}}
   \end{figure}

   \end{document}
```

Comment: I have an error on your code: `Unknown function of' (in 'of u'). [...  = of u,label=above:$\scriptsize{J_{i}}$]]`

Comment: Your MWE doesn't work, you need the `positioning` Tikz-library. You can (barely) fit the drawings besides each other if you remove the `\clip` command from the second picture. The empty lines between the two `tikzpicture` environments will give you a new paragraph for the second picture, if you remove those they will be placed side-by-side.

Comment: Thanks Max! I follow your advice and now I could place them side-by-side. I still have the issue that I need more gap between them and I need them both to be under the text. The text now is compiling well.

Comment: Now I'm improving and I could do a nice space between them using \hspace{1.2cm}. The only one is how to place them right down a text.

Comment: for positioning figure below text you need to add option `[!h]`. if on the page is enough place, figure should follow this text. otherwise it will appear on the top of the next page.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the various questions were resolved in comments.